# Intercept and log incoming message to endpoint

Tags: java, apache-camel, cxf, javabeans

I want to log the incoming SOAP in my beans setup but I don't know how to intercept the requested body.

I found out if I add **?dataFormat=MESSAGE** to my CxfEndpoint it shows the xml input but messes up the dataFormat that provides the **addBookTransformer**.

```
<from uri="cxf:bean:CxfEndpoint?dataFormat=MESSAGE" />
```

This is my setup

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="CxfEndpoint"
    address="/host/addBook"
    endpointName="a:addBookEndpoint"
    serviceName="a:addBookService"
    wsdlURL="wsdl/add-book.wsdl"
    serviceClass="com.library.AddBookEndpoint"
    xmlns:a="http://library.com"/>

<bean id="addBookTransformer" class="com.library.bookshelf.AddBookTransformer"/>

<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route id="addBook" streamCache="true">
        <from uri="cxf:bean:CxfEndpoint" />
        <process ref="addBookTransformer" />
        <log message="${body}"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

Is there a way to itercept and log the incoming post request data?

Comment: try wiretap and use that to log message.

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do wiretap for this

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route id="addBook" streamCache="true">
        <from uri="cxf:bean:CxfEndpoint" />
        <process ref="addBookTransformer" />
        <wireTap uri="direct:tap"/>
        <to uri="mock:result"/>
        <log message="${body}"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

A copy of the exchange is sent to `direct:tap` which you can read and process however you want.

For example we could just log the message like this. You could also add another processor.

```
<route id="wiretapped" streamCache="true">
     <from uri="direct:tap" />
     <log message="${body}"/>
</route>
```

Here is the [documentation](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/wireTap-eip.html) for this.

Comment: This gives me this error: org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectConsumerNotAvailableException: No consumers available on endpoint: Endpoint[direct://tap].

Comment: you have to write a consumer for `direct:tap` the above code makes a copy of the exchange and sends it to direct:tap endpoint. You have to declare another route from direct:tap and do whatever u want

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a very well known requirement. The pattern that provides the solution is a Filter and exists as a concept in the very early versions of J2EE spec. Back in times when we (the dinosaurs) wrote servlets, you could add a Filter to your servlet that intercepts both, request before it gets to your servlet and response after it is generated by your servlet but before it is sent to the client-side. In your Filter, you can log info, redirect it to a different destination, deny it or do anything you like. The same concept remains intact. You need to define a filter for all or some of your end-points and in your filter do the logging. If you work with Spring boot here is the article that describes how to add Filters for end-points in Spring Boot: [How to Define a Spring Boot Filter?](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-add-filter)